# SQL join based on select as column name

Tags: sql, join, select

So in one table I can use a `replace` and `charindex` to extract a specific ID that relates to a PK in another table, I want to then join the data from the other table based on the trimmed value, how can I do this?

```
select top 100 *, Replace(Left(LogValue,Charindex(';', LogValue) - 1) ,'RtaId=', '') as TaskID, PrmRoutingTask.*    
  from SytLog       
       inner join  PrmRoutingTask on RtaId = TaskID
 where LogTableName like '%Routing%' and LogValue like '%RtaAniId=397%' 
 order by 5 desc;
```

The problem I get is that the temp column name I create (`TaskID`) is not working in the inner join where in fact the results of TaskID have the reference to the `RtaId` in the `RoutingTask` table.

Comment: What table is `LogValue` from?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: "not working" is not helpful. We can expect that when pinned down this will be a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `LogValue` belongs to the first table you can use the column named `TaskID` if you produce a subquery as a table expression of the main query.

For example you can produce the column in the table expression `a` by doing:

```
select top 100 
  a.*,
  PrmRoutingTask.*

from (
  select *,
    Replace(Left(LogValue,Charindex(';', LogValue) - 1) ,'RtaId=', '') as TaskID
  from SytLog
) a

inner join PrmRoutingTask on PrmRoutingTask.RtaId = a.TaskID

where LogTableName like '%Routing%' 
  and LogValue like '%RtaAniId=397%' 

order by 5 desc
```